Stack Exchange guidelines on image sharing
Under what conditions can one use images found in the internet on Stack Exchange?
Particularly images from Wikipedia.
Is it sufficient to supply a link to the page where I borrowed it from?
What are specific Stack Exchange guidelines or meta-posts?
Related: Usage of images from internet

Each image on wikimedia includes a section about its specific license which tells you if you can use it and what you have to do if you use it, e.g. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Anas_platyrhynchos_(mixed_pair)_(32428014687).jpg#Licensing

The relevant guideline here is the law/licensing. Most images require you to attribute the copyright holder, and unless they’re under a permissive licence you may not be allowed to use it at all unless you have a Fair Use argument. But in practice nobody follows copyright law precisely and nothing is likely to be enforced here unless the owner complains.

@Jeremy some points are unclear here: 1) law/licensing of which country/jurisdiction? 1) If the owner complains - what is the SE responsibility? And what are the potential sanctions against the user?

@RogerV. America probably but the basics of copyright law have been standard across the world for a century: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention. Generally there’s no penalty except for having your post removed and a warning, unless it’s repeated after warning or it’s seen as part of plagiarism. SE generally isn’t liable until they’re informed IIUC IANAL.

Image or text doesn't matter. Just do the same thing you'd do when copying text from somewhere else. That includes making sure you have the right to publish it under the content license here and that you fulfill the terms of the license.

"If the owner complains - what is the SE responsibility?" if the owner complaints through post/comment/mod flag/blog/social media, then nothing happens. Only if the owner sends a DMCA Takedown request, then SE has to take down the whole post.

Under Creative Commons, when posting images sourced from Wikipedia, it should be sufficient to link to a Wikipedia / Wikimedia page containing the image so interested readers can follow the link trail to find the author info, etc. After all, Wikipedia itself doesn't print the image author's name directly on the article page.

@PM2Ring I think that’s incorrect legal advice. Wikipedia requires you to go to a different page… which is on Wikipedia. Wikipedia is providing the attribution for Wikipedia. If you’re not Wikipedia, you can’t rely on their attribution, because you have a legal requirement to provide the attribution yourself.

@Jeremy I Am Not A Lawyer, and I wasn't attempting to give actual legal advice. I was merely stating my personal interpretation of what I believe should apply, based on my reading of various material on the Creative Commons site.

According to https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/License_Versions#Attribution_reasonable_to_means.2C_medium.2C_and_context "In 4.0, the manner of attribution is explicitly allowed to be reasonable to the means, medium, and context of how one shares a work [...] Reasonableness applies to all attribution requirements"

Personally, I believe a link trail to the source material that leads to the author info is reasonable. In fact, it's superior to a simple plain text mention of the author's name. In the explicit case of Wikipedia, I expect that they will maintain correct author info. In contrast, I don't have ultimate control of what happens to material I publish on Stack Exchange. Does it really matter who's sites the link trail passes through? IMHO, what matters is that you can get the required info by following the link trail.

Your personal obligations are given in the Terms of Service, under the 'Acceptable Use Policy':

Unauthorized Use of Intellectual Property
You may not post content that infringes on another’s intellectual
property right, including trademark, copyright, patent, trade secret,
or other intellectual property right. While the use of copyrighted
material does not constitute copyright infringement in all cases,
users should be careful when using copyrighted content without the
permission of those who created it and adhere to any license
requirements (e.g., attribution, notice, etc.). Stack Exchange
complies with the Digital Millennium Copyright Act ("DMCA"), and you
may view our process for reporting DMCA complaints.

Note that other users, including moderators, are not required to police your compliance with this. Nevertheless, the Code of Conduct, which moderators are required to enforce, does insist on proper attribution for content that you did not create yourself, under the 'Inauthentic Usage Policy':

[...] we do not allow what we define as inauthentic usage of our systems,
such as:

[...]
Plagiarizing or copying content from websites, books, or other online    and offline tools without proper attribution in a manner
that violates our referencing standards.


The referencing standards are geared to written work; but equate to providing the name of the creator & a link to the source of the image (or the next-best answers to "who created this image?" & "where is it published?").
See site Metas for any site-specific policies or norms that may additionally apply.
